# Calling shell script within a script

Tags: linux, shell

```
Below are my two script codes:
**a.sh**

#!/bin/sh

SRC_PATH="/xx/xxxx"
HOST='ftp.xxx.xxx.com'
USER='xxxx'
PASS='xxx'
FTP_SRC_PATH='out'

**b.sh** 
#!/bin/sh

/xx/xxx/a.sh

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASS
binary
prompt off
cd $FTP_SRC_PATH
lcd $SRC_PATH
mget IMS_*.ZIP
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

My issue is when I am running b.sh , it is not calling a.sh and using the variables defined in it to connect to ftp server.
I have seen many solutions already online but things doesn't seem to work.
Please help

Comment: You do not want to "call" the other shellscript because calling would make it have its variables **on its own**. You want to "source" it so the variables are also visible to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can include `a.sh`with the dot command:

```
. /xx/xxx/a.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call the script a from within b as follows:

sh ./a.sh

Make sure both the shell scripts are in same file path. Also, you can pass the value within scripts as follows:

sh ./a.sh $d $e

The values passed here can be accessed as $1 $2.

Comment: This will not help reading the variables from `a.sh` into `b.sh`.

Comment: No, the `sh` command executes a script but doesn't import variables. It is equivalent to the direct execution of the script if the executable flag is set. This is done by OP, and he states that this doesn't work. He will import the variables and not pass them as arguments.

Comment: @macmoonshine it accepts positional parameters passed along.

Comment: Yes, of course this works, but that is not the question here.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

a.sh:

## !/bin/bash

```
yourvalue="test"
sh ./b.sh $yourvalue
```

and I'm able to access the variable passed here in the shell script b as $1.